# AngularJS' $interval.cancel not working

Tags: angularjs

As stated in the title,

every time I try to use **$interval.cancel** to cancel an existing interval, it doesn't work.

```
window.recordedAudio = undefined;

var isRecordingComplete = $interval(function(){
    console.log(window.recordedAudio);
    if (window.recordedAudio!=undefined) $timeout.cancel(isRecordingComplete);
},100);

$timeout(function(){
    window.recordedAudio = "abc";
},2000);
```

In fact, when **window.recordedAudio!= undefined** (window.recordedAudio is set to "abc" after 2000ms), the **$interval** keeps looping and at the same time the

```
console.log(window.recordedAudio)
```

keeps being printed (+- 10 times undefined and finally abc but it keeps printing abc rather than just stop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `$interval` and `$timeout.cancel`.

Comment: you are totally right. I can't accept the answer right now but I'll do it as soon as it lets me. thank you :)